# VB.NET: Changes to application.dll.config file does not reflect inside system

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I'm quite new to this app.config function. Hope someone can show me the road on this.

I have a solution which comprise of 5 projects and one of them just to retrieve the value from the app.config file to be read by other projects. So, in the app.config file, i have my connection string stated inside and i can use it nicely.

After i built the projects, it will convert my app.config file to appname.dll.config file and it can be seen in the bin/Release folder. I copy all these projects bin/release content to another folder to have all those files stay in one place.

My question is, which config file should i change if i want to change the connection string username (for example) WIHOUT building the project and transfer again? I changed the value inside appname.dll.config file but it does not reflect when the program run. It's still taking the old connection string.

Hope someone can help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only the appname.exe.config file is ever read.  DLLs cannot have config files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the app.config associated with the exe project (command line or GUI) is the one that holds the changes app wide.  Check for the appname.exe.config file and make your necessary changes there for connection strings, etc...

[update]
Just thought of something else... if it's a web project you can use the web.config in the main webproject to configure your changes

Comment: This projects are actually Windows services. Seems there are no appname.exe.config file generated.How do i make sure the file is being generated? Thanks

Comment: Whatever the main windows service dll is then  you would make alterations there. Any additional libraries that it calls will also use the main app.config file.

Comment: But when i make my alteration on the appname.dll.config, it would not take effect as its still taking the old value. If changes made to app.config then i would need to build it before it reflect inside the appname.dll.config. What should i do to only change the config while avoiding compiling it again. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks